# each row of the table having check box. but by clicking on check box it is not selecting that row text value

Tags: javascript

In html table i have checkbox for each row. by clicking on check box it has to select person name of the table. but it is not working. and i want to provide validation for this check box user can select only check box at a time.

HTML:

```
<table id="personTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th style="width: 10px;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check_selectall_b" onclick="selectAll(this)"/>
                SA
            </th>
            <th>person name</th>
            <th> address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="person_table">
        <% @persons.all.each do |person| %>
        <tr id="tr_prns_<%=person.id %>">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="checkBox[]" 
                       onchange="personClickedBox(this.name)"/>
            </td>
            <td class="person"  style="word-break:break-all;">
                <%= person.name%> 
            </td>
            <td class="person"  style="word-break:break-all;">
                <%= person.address%> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function personClickedBox(checkBoxName){

var values = new Array();

$.each($("input[name='"+checkBoxName+"']:checked").closest("td").next("td"), 
    function () {
       values.input($(this).text().trim());
    }); 
}
```

by clicking on check box it has to select person name

Answer (score 0):

Your code get the clicked check box value perfectly. What you need to do is add a css style to select the specific raw

Comment: im getting the value in $(this).text().trim() but not able to pass this value to var values = new Array();

Comment: Try this values.push($(this).text().trim());